# How to iterate through child components in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm attempting to have a parent component employ a foreach to iterate through child components in Blazor. For example, I have a Button component and want to be able to nest that in a ButtonGroup component that adds padding around each Button. My code returns a "The type arguments for method...cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." Not sure how to accomplish. Any help appreciated.

**Index.razor**

```html
<ButtonGroup>
  <Button>Howdy</Button>
  <Button>Doody</Button>
 </ButtonGroup>
```

**Button.razor**

```html
<a href="@Url" class="btn btn-primary">@ChildContent</a>

@code {
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public string Url { get; set; }
```

**ButtonGroup.razor**

```html
@typeparam TItem

<div class="flex flex-wrap py-16 mx-n4">
  @foreach (var item in Items)
  {
  <div class="px-4 d-ib">
    @ChildContent(item)
  </div>
  }
</div>

@code {
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildContent { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `ChildItems` and where is `Items` set in the `<ButtonGroup>` ?

Comment: Typo. `ChildItems` should be `Items`.

Comment: OK, but where is `<ButtonGroup Items=...>` ?

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I'm looking at component templating to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, but don't have a connected dataset. Is there some way to capture components passed through ChildContent ?

Comment: You should at least thank me and the second answerer, Nik P,  for trying to help you . Please, make sure you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you both. I don't have enough karma to upvote anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to approach using `ChildContent` a bit differently than you have it. By convention with Blazor, `ChildContent` is used to dictate where to insert the markup that is placed between the opening and closing tags of your component, in circumstances where you have only one section that needs a fragment. That means that your Button.razor component is written correctly.

Things are going sideways when you get into your button group however, and there are a couple of approaches you can take. Templated components will get you there, but this can be much simpler if you use nested components with ChildContent to get what you need.

Starting with your ButtonGroup.razor, you can simplify so the button group just takes child content and places it, and in your case will be a simple wrapper so the CSS does what it needs to do:

```cs
<div class="flex flex-wrap py-16 mx-n4">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
 
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
  
}
```

Note that since this is a simple wrapper, you can remove the generic `TItem` and just use this as a layout tool.

Then, step up the tree one level, and *here* is where you iterate your list, and you should be specific with your components nesting at this level. Note the nesting of `Button` and `ButtonGroup`, and I assume the type you use for ItemType in your list has properties for `Url` and `ButtonName`, but you get the point and you can constrain where needed.

```cs
<ButtonGroup>
    @foreach (var item in Items ) {
        <div class="px-4 d-ib">
            <Button Url="@item.Url">@item.ButtonName</Button>
        </div>
</ButtonGroup>

@code {

    [Parameter] public IReadOnlyList<ItemType> Items { get; set; }

}
```

This way, whatever is nested between the tags of each component has a place in the markup that is generated, so your `ButtonGroup` surrounds all your `Button` components and they in turn render the button names, but **everything** is still being dictated and controlled at the top level.

You could of course do the same thing with Templated Components and there are times they are necessary, but for your use case they would require roughly the same or more code at the top level and be way overkill for what you are trying to do.